# Rewriting R plot code into Python using Matplotlib but not getting same results

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, linear-algebra

I've tried to rewrite code for a plot from R into Python, but have gotten a resulting diagram that doesn't look right. The dots of the Python scatter plot seem to fall on one line. Am wondering if I've used the wrong function in `np.random.normal` in replacing `rnorm`?

Here's the original R code:

```
g <- 9.8 ##meters per second
n <- 25
tt <- seq(0,3.4,len=n) ##time in secs, t is a base function
f <- 56.67  - 0.5*g*tt^2
y <-  f + rnorm(n,sd=1)

plot(tt,y,ylab="Distance in meters",xlab="Time in seconds")
lines(tt,f,col=2)
```

Here's the attempted rewrite in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = 9.8 # meters per second
n = 25 
tt = np.linspace(0, 3.4, num = n) 
f = 56.67 - 0.5 * g * tt**2
y = f + np.random.normal(n, scale=1.0)

plt.scatter(tt, y, edgecolor="black", facecolors="white")
plt.plot(tt, f, color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Time in seconds")
plt.ylabel("Distance in meters")
plt.show()
```

The first one's the R (desired) plot:
[image: Here's the R plot]

Here's however the Python plot:
[image: Here's the Python plot]

Comment: Interesting, have you checked the documentation of np.random.normal that it exactly matches what rnorm is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the arguments to `np.random.normal()` in the wrong order. The first argument is the mean of the sample, which you are currently giving as `25` and so your both curves are largely offset

The correct way is to pass the size of your desired random array as the last argument `size=n`

```
y = f + np.random.normal(scale=1.0, size=n)
```

where `size` is the number of elements. The [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) state the following:

> **Parameters**:
>   **loc :** ***float or array_like of floats***
>    Mean (“centre”) of the distribution.
>
> **scale : *float or array_like of floats***
>   Standard deviation (spread or “width”) of the distribution.
>
> **size** ***: int or tuple of ints, optional***
>   Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k samples are drawn. If size is None (default), a single value is returned if loc and scale are both scalars. Otherwise, np.broadcast(loc, scale).size samples are drawn.